# GitHub source misreporting its file location

Tags: git, compiler-errors, cache-control

We have very strange behaviour from gitHub. We have been pulling from gitHub no problem until two days ago. A local copy of a class appears to have its origin on my collaborators machine as evidenced in the trace stack below:

Exception fault: ArgumentError: error must be either Class or Matcher
    at global/org.hamcrest.core::throws()[E:\hudson\jobs\hamcrest-as3\workspace\hamcrest\src\org\hamcrest\core\throws.as:34]

```
at modules.channelSelector.model.proxy::CS_SkinProxy/spriteLoadCompleteHandler([/Users/MY_COLLABORATOR/His file path/CS_SkinProxy.as:85]
at org.osflash.signals::Slot/execute()[/Users/ME/My file path/Slot.as:88]
at org.osflash.signals::OnceSignal/dispatch()[/Users/ME/My file path/OnceSignal.as:132]
at sem.bitmap::BitmapUtil/completeHandler()[/Users/ME/My file path/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at com.greensock.loading.core::LoaderCore/_completeHandler()[/Users/ME/My file path/LoaderCore.as:399]
at com.greensock.loading::LoaderMax/_loadNext()[/Users/ME/My file path/LoaderMax.as:819]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
```

We have tried everything. Committing the changes to the class and pushing. Removing the offending class from the gitHub source via git rm -file --cached -f, file deletion etc. Committing this deletion and then pulling again. Rebuilding the class when its not a part of the GitHub source current repository. All with the same stack trace telling us the class is not on my machine!

Any code changes to this CS_SkinProxy class are not updating either despite the fact the other updates outside of this class are updating as expected. Basically we have a new switch case statement which jumps to the wrong statement,causing the Hamcrest error. All this happens on FDT and IntelliJ. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ian

Comment: As a footnote to the problem even when I refactor the class with a different name, updating all references etc, it still thinks the old file is in use on my collaborators file path. References to the file are obviously cached somewhere beyond my control.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar things happen when a co-worker inadvertently commits a debug build of a binary.  Debug builds often contain references to machine specific file locations.

To make matters worse, once committed a debug binary will not be ignored even if in a `.gitignore` file.  That means a pull can easily put the binary back, even after it has been rebuilt.

To fix this, if indeed it is the issue, the binary will need to be removed from the repository history, which is discussed in this question: [Remove sensitive files and their commits from git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history).

Regarding your footnote, changing the class name along with the file and all references to it will have little effect.  A debug binary is built at the assembly level and is the compilation of all the files it contains.  This would change the binary file, but not its name since that is generally determined at the assembly level as well.